# Does N-gram language model for text generation are more efficient than Neural Network language models?

Tags: nlp, lstm, rnn, text-generation, ngrams

I recently build an language model with N-gram model for text generation and for change I started exploring Neural Network for text generation. One thing I observed that  the previous model results were better than the LSTM  model even when both where built using same corpus.

Comment: This depends on the amount on you data, with much data neural nets will work better. By the way, neural nets are also type of ML algorithm.

Comment: Please add a sample data on which your observation is based. NN needs more data.

Comment: N grams will not be able to capture the context like BERT, ELMo and other context deep learning based approaches.